# javascript apache cordova alert and document.write

Tags: javascript, apache, cordova

i am new to apache cordova i have some issues with javascript code using coedova  for some reason the following code doesn't work for me

```
<p>Hello, your application is ready!</p>
<script>
    alert("Hello");
    document.write("Hello");
</script>
```

the only output i get is the html tag

Hello, your application is ready!

the javascript code doesn't work

any reasons for that ?

Comment: You are not listening to the deviceready event. Please read the documentation: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

Answer (score 0):

The following code wont work because you are just declaring it. But you need to invoke it, which you can do by putting it inside an immediately invoking function(IIF)

```
 (function(){
alert("Hello");
document.write("Hello");    
 }())

Note the braces around the function
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yoao1yx8/)